# Change GTK themes on the fly

Tags: settings, gtk2, gtk3

I'm not running xfce4 or gnome, so I can't use their respective settings manager.

Now I want to alter the GTK theme of all running apps, do you think that's possible? I think there's a signal or whatever can do that, but I couldn't find one.

Any ideas? It should works for both gtk2 and gtk3 apps.

Comment: You can't change theme for running application, you should restart it.

Comment: @Eddy_Em  hmm, but xfce4-settings-manager can do that, am I wrong?

Comment: Can xfce4 be reloaded? If it does, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: In gtk2 there were some functions, capable of rereading .rc files with themes, but I don't know, how to invoke them: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-Resource-Files.html#gtk-rc-reparse-all.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: Gtk themes can be changed on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [gtk-theme-switch2](http://muhri.net/nav.php3?node=gts). It's a command-line utility that will apply whichever theme you tell it to; it also comes with a GUI if necessary:

[image: Screenshot]